# Array of dynamic Type objects in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

Short form: My question is similar to this other stackoverflow answer, except that I need the Type of 'dynamic' rather than string etc

[Dynamically create an array of Type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697230/dynamically-create-an-array-of-type-in-c-sharp)

Basically, I'm running a query using Dapper, which supports object mapping up to 7 objects -- I need 8.

When doing 7 it looks like:

```
connection.Query<dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic, dynamic>(sql, (obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7) => {...});
```

When doing 8 it's supposed to be:

```
connection.Query<dynamic>(sql, Type[], (objArray) => {...});
```

Where Type[] is an array of types -- in this case, 8 dynamic types.

I've tried all sorts of things from

```
var types = new Type[]{
    dynamic,
    dynamic,
    dynamic,
    dynamic,
    dynamic,
    dynamic,
    dynamic,
    dynamic
}
```

to

```
var types = new Type[]{
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"),
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"),
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"),
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"),
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"),
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"),
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject"),
    Type.GetType("System.Dynamic.DynamicObject")
}
```

And various others. None of which works.

I'm figuring since 'dynamic' is rather the absence of a type, that maybe I'm approaching this slightly wrong?

Anyway, any ideas?

Comment: Don't do that.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Whence cometh `IDbConnection.Query`? This must be an extension method since [the interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.idbconnection) defines no such method, but from where? What technology are you using? Or is your problem that you want to *write* such a method?

Comment: `dynamic` is not a type - is just means that any binding will be done at run-time based on the _actual_ type of the object.  Can you add more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is this for a dapper call? if it is (as it seems to me) you got all worng, calrify it and I can post an example.

Comment: It is dapper. I'm maintaining existing code, so I can't say anything for the quality of what's already there. I'm primarily a node and rails guy, so this is rather unfamiliar to me.

Answer (score 1):

> **[C# Reference: `dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)**
>
> Type `dynamic` behaves like type `object` in most circumstances. However, operations that contain expressions of type `dynamic` are not resolved or type checked by the compiler. The compiler packages together information about the operation, and that information is later used to evaluate the operation at run time. As part of the process, **variables of type dynamic are compiled into variables of type `object`**. Therefore, type `dynamic` exists only at compile time, not at run time.

So you should just pass this :

```
var types = Enumerable.Repeat(typeof(object), 8).ToArray();
```